# Contact Form Not Sending Information

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I recently got some help in another topic and was able to receive an email from my contact form, but all of the information save for the message text was excluded, and it was sent from "Apache". Is there any reason this might be happening?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "______@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

$to ='______@gmail.com';
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "We've received your information, thank you"

if($send_contact){
echo "We've received your contact information, thank you";
}
else {
echo "Error, please try again";
} }
?>


<form action = "../mail.php"method="POST">
<p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
<p>Company</p> <input type="text" name="company">
<p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
<p>Phone</p> <input type="text" name="phone">
<p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="4" cols="25"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong variable name you have used.

Please change the last param of the mail call from $header to $mailHeader

```
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

to

```
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$mailHeader);
```

Append all information what you need before sending. Use the below code,

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$messageContent = $name."\n".$company."\n".$email."\n".$phone."\n".$message."\n";

$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$messageContent,$mailHeader);
```

Comment: It still sent me a message, but none of the information appeared.

Comment: where you are sending the information in mail functionality? you are not sending. then how it will come. only message variable is sent and not other variables like phone, company, email.

Answer (score 0):

Edit this

```
send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

to

```
send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$mailheader);
```

and you can also send like this

```
send_contact = main($to,$subject,$formcontact,$mailheader);
```

if you want...and

sending mail in php is not a one-step process. mail() returns true/false, but even if it returns true, it doesn't mean the message is going to be sent. all mail() does is add the message to the queue(using sendmail or whatever you set in php.ini)

there is no reliable way to check if the message has been sent in php. you will have to look through the mail server logs.

Comment: and where is `$formcontent` ? :)

Comment: In the mail function through the headers we cn send the formcontent but the questioner didnt mentioned it on mail function so I didnt mentioned in my....ofcourse its not a manidatory to send formcontact right..??